# Rails 4 ActiveRecord Includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am trying to understand ActiveRecord includes. I am trying to retrieve both Folders and Grids in a single query. I have associated Grids and Folders in ActiveAdmin. Why does this query not return Grid associated data? How do I get Folder plus Grid associated data?

```
irb(main):002:0> Folder.includes(:grids)
      Folder Load (85.4ms)  SELECT `folders`.* FROM `folders`
      Grid Load (93.1ms)  SELECT `grids`.* FROM `grids` WHERE `grids`.`folder_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
    => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Folder id: 1, name: "Red", created_at: "2014-03-14 06:02:09", updated_at: "2014-03-14 06:03:46">, #<Folder id: 2, name: "Yellow", created_at: "2014-03-14 06:03:33", updated_at: "2014-03-14 06:04:02">, #<Folder id: 3, name: "Blue", created_at: "2014-03-14 06:04:20", updated_at: "2014-03-14 06:04:20">]>

class Grid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :folder
  has_many :role_grids
  has_many :roles, :through => :role_grids
end

class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :grids
end
```

schema:

```
create_table "folders", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "grids", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "folder_id"
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually retrieving all of the Grid data. If you were to check any of the folders for their grids, they would all be there without executing any more SQL queries.

The point of using `includes` is to eager load associations, avoiding the n+1 queries problem.

A good write up on eager loading, and why n+1s are bad, is here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: But I do not see the Grid data in Rails console. This query in a controller only returns Folders with no Grids?
folders = Folder.includes(:grids)
 render json: @folders, root: false
[{"id":1,"name":"Red"},{"id":2,"name":"Yellow"},{"id":3,"name":"Blue"}]

Comment: Is there a way to output the entire object inclusive of associations?

Comment: I see the Grids when iterating the folders object. I guess the question I have is how do I render all associated data?
render json: @folders, :include => :grids, root: false